# Выскакивает изображение из своего места при наведении

Tags: css, sass

Сделал увеличение при помощи :hover и она перескакивает в нижнюю левую часть. Пишу с помощью SASS.

```
.content_gallerey{
    background-image: url(../images/logo_bgr.png);display: inline-block;
    h2{
        text-align: center;font-size: 2.5em;font-family: "PlayfairDisplaySC-Italic";
    }
    figure{
        display: inline-block;
        img{
            width: 580px;height: 460px;
            max-width: 360px; max-height: 280px;overflow: hidden;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        }
        img:hover{
            max-width: 720px;max-height: 560px;transition: 1.5s;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
            -o-transform: scale(1.1);overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что нужно сделать то?

Comment: html добавьте же

Comment: http://pamyatniki.com.by/galerey.php
тут html код. Чтобы изображения не перескакивали а шло замещение поверх всех при увеличении, а то 1 строка нормально а остальные уходят в разные стороны. На сайт залил убрав css код на увеличение т.к. срочно надо было брательнику.